# The exponential map is neither injective nor surjective when $n\ge 2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Consider the exponential map

$$\exp: M_n(\mathbb R) \to \{g:\det(g)>0 \}.$$

When $n=1$ this is bijective. But what happens when $n>1$? I was trying to come up with examples that fails the injectivity/surjectivity but I don't have some good examples in mind. It would be great if there is a series of examples that fails all $n\ge 2$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about $\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1}?$

Comment: @AnginaSeng are you saying that it is not in the image and thus fails the surjectivity? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $exp(it)$ it is not injective where $i$ is represented in the basis $(1,i)$ by $\pmatrix{0& -1\cr 1&0}$.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get this example... it is not as simple to me as $\exp(it):\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ not being injective. Could you explicitly show me two matrices that are mapped to the same thing in terms of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @NoOne If Tsemo's matrix is $J$, then $\exp(tJ)=(\cos t)I+(\sin t)J$.

Comment: $exp(2i\pi)=cos(2\pi)+isin(2\pi)$

Comment: are you saying that $\exp [2\pi \pmatrix{0& -1\cr 1&0} ]=\exp(0)$?

Comment: exactly, as you asked it is an interesting example

Comment: Thanks, it takes me a while to believe this. Do you think you can show me the noninjectivity for all $n\ge 2$?

Comment: You can define a similar matrix for each $n>2$ by seeing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @NoOne To clarify Tsemo's hint further, note that 
$$
\exp \pmatrix{A&0\\0&0_{n \times n}} = \pmatrix{\exp(A) & 0\\0 & I_{n \times n}}
$$
for any square matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gives an example where injectivity fails. For surjectivity, the comment on your answer gives the example
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1},
$$
and indeed there is no matrix $X$ such that $A = \exp(X)$. To see that this is the case, suppose for the purpose of contradiction that such an $X$ exists. Note that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $X$, $e^\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $e^X$. It follows that in order for $e^X$ to have an eigenvalue of $-1$, its eigenvalues must be of the form  $\pi k i$ for some odd integer $k$.

Because $X$ is a real matrix, its eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs, which is to say that both $\pm \pi ki$ must be eigenvalues of $X$ for some odd $k$.  Thus, $X$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$, which means that $e^X$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ with $-1$ as its only eigenvalue, which means that $e^X = -I$, so $e^{X}\neq A$.

Comment: Where you say that for $e^X$ to have an eigenvalue of $-1$, its eigenvalues must be either $i$ or $-i$, don't you really mean its (i.e., $X$'s) eigenvalues must be odd multiples of $\pi i$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, that was a weird mistake for me to make, thanks for catching that